# how to insert array of data to database (for example add more products to cart ) using api

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

Hi all am trying to insert array of data to database using api in laravel .my task is i need to insert data from postman using some paramters(inputs)
when i run url the data is not inserting into database .

getting output status::true. am not getting any errors .how to solve this to insert data?

below is my code:

```
public function addToCart(){
     $input =  Input::all();
     $data['status'] = 0;
     $data['error'] = true;
    // print_r($input);
     $carty=array($input['cart']);
     if(isset($input['user_id']) && isset($carty)> 0 ){
          foreach($carty as $key => $val){
              if(!empty($val['quantity']) && !empty($val['price']) && !empty($val['sku']) && !empty($val['qrcode'])  && !empty($val['product_id']))
              {
                  echo "here";
                  $totalPrice = $val['quantity']* $val['price'];
                  $cartId = [];
                  $cartId[] = DB::table('jocom_cart')->insertGetId(array(
                    'user_id'   => $input['user_id'],
                    'product_id'      => $val['product_id'],
                    'sku'      => $val['sku'],
                    'quantity'       => $val['quantity'],
                    'price' => $val['price'],
                    'total_price' => $totalPrice,
                    'qrcode' => $val['qrcode']
                  ));
             }
         }
      }
      else{
          $data['message'] = 'All field are required.';

      }
      return Response::json($data);   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some syntax errors in your posted code

```
$input =  Input::all()
```

Must be (**;** missing)

```
$input =  Input::all();
```

and

```
DB::table('jocom_cart')>insertGetId
```

must be (with **->**, not **>**)

```
DB::table('jocom_cart')->insertGetId
```

Hope it's could resolved the problem

Comment: Also , i don't know which laravel version you used. But the **all** method did not exist in **Input** Facade. Try **get** method istead (Laravel 5.6). [See Laravel API Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get)

Comment: am using laravel 4.2 .i corrected syntax errors but still same problem

Comment: so , you should check the requirement condition then see the request input passed the **if** test.